# center div with Font Awesome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment, font-awesome

I have a site I am making with Bootstrap  3.3.5. I would like to center the div with the icons and I also want the icons centered, like what text-align: center; would do if it was just text and not the Fonat Awesome icons. This is what I have tried so far, the css is in my css folder and in the custom.css page.

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-1-5 { width: 20%; }
  .col-md-2-5 { width: 40%; }
  .col-md-3-5 { width: 60%; }
  .col-md-4-5 { width: 80%; }
  .col-md-5-5 { width: 100%; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-1-5 { width: 20%; }
  .col-lg-2-5 { width: 40%; }
  .col-lg-3-5 { width: 60%; }
  .col-lg-4-5 { width: 80%; }
  .col-lg-5-5 { width: 100%; }
}

.show-grid [class^=col-] span,
.container-fluid .show-grid [class^=col-] {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

[class^=col-] {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row show-grid">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4-5 col-lg-1-5 text-center"><span class=""><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nationalkitchencabinets.kitchensolutions" target="_blank">

      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-google fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5-5 col-lg-1-5 text-center"><span class=""><a href="https://appsto.re/us/IxCMbb.i" target="_blank">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-android fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3-5 col-lg-1-5 text-center"><span class=""><a href="mailto:info@nationalkitchencabinets.com">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3-5 col-lg-1-5 text-center"><span class=""><a href="https://www.facebook.com/NationalKitchenCabinets/" target="_blank">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3-5 col-lg-1-5 text-center"><span class=""><a href="tel:1-413-374-2939">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                            </span>
                            </a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is what it looks like now, the icons are left aligned, 
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `justify-content:space-around` with [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements that you are trying to align are `block` elements, so you simply need to use `margin: 0 auto` rather than `text-align: center`.

```
.show-grid [class^=col-] span,
.container-fluid .show-grid [class^=col-] {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Should be:

```
.show-grid [class^=col-] span,
.container-fluid .show-grid [class^=col-] {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I've created a Bootply showcasing this [here](http://www.bootply.com/uAMHTdkhzv).

**UPDATE**:

A temporary hack to have the icons display next to each other on mobile would be something like the following:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 20% !important;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

However, this is a workaround, and you should really simply set a smaller column width. Bootstrap columns always add up to 12, and `col-sm-6` refers to '6 columns on small devices'. Typically, you'd use something like `col-sm-2 col-md-12 col-lg-12` to represent that each element should take up the full width on medium and large devices, and only take up one-sixth of the width on small devices. Of course, 12 isn't divisible by 5, so you'd have to come up with your own workaround, such as centralisation or padding ;)

A secondary fiddle showcasing the hack is available [here](http://www.bootply.com/ndfGrSMHyl).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly how I want it to appear in full width screens. I can't believe I didn't think to use that. When it's a narrow screen, like tablet or phone, the icons stack on top of each other in the center. Is there a way to make that so they are also side by side?

Comment: That's a job that BootStrap **should** easily be able to handle. Simply change `col-sm-6` to `col-sm-2`, and each will one **should** adapt correctly. However, you are using invalid Bootstrap classes (like `col-md-3-5`), and controlling them with custom media queries, which I'm assuming is part of why that doesn't work. I'd need a bit of time to look into why it's not working for you.

Comment: I'll try it. I searched a lot tonight because I really wanted 5 side by side icons and that code I posted is from a lot of Google searching.

Comment: I've just updated my code to provide a temporary hack, and a brief explanation of how Bootstrap's columns work -- I'd recommend reading up on that, so you can avoid using custom media queries almost entirely ;)

Comment: Awesome :) Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it fully answered your question :)